# Possible to extract multiple key/value pairs (links) from string in CSV and migrate into multiple link field

Tags: 8, migrations, importing-exporting

I am using migrate source CSV and trying to extract a string which contains multiple key/value pairs of links in format:

```
"Google.com|https://google.com,Yahoo.com|https://yahoo.com"
```

I need to save the values into a multiple link field.

The logic I need to run is:

```
- Explode the string on comma ,
- Iterate each item
  - Explode string on pipe |
    - Extract index 0
      - Store to field_link/title
    - Extract index 1
      - Store to field_link/uri
```

I have it working using a custom process plugin but would like to try and achieve this if possible through chaining of the core process plugins in the migration config yml file.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution to solve a similar problem:

```
temp_data:
  -
    source: data
    plugin: explode
    delimiter: ','
  -
    plugin: explode
    delimiter: '|'
destination_field:
  plugin: sub_process
  source: '@temp_data'
  process:
    field_attr_1: '0'
    field_attr_2: '1'
    field_attr_3: '2'
```

Hope it helps.

Regards,
 M.

Comment: This really helped me. Thank you!