# Migrating 2 fields into a link field

Tags: migrations, 10

I'm looking to migrate two fields on D7 (one a link field, the other a text field) into a single link field on D10.

The meat of the migration is here:

```
source:
  plugin: d7_paragraphs_item
  bundle: BUNDLE
process:
  d10_link_field:
    plugin: field_link
    source: d7_link_field
  d10_link_field/title: d7_title_field/value
```

This is resulting in a title of NULL in the d10_link_field.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrate Multiple URLs from a Spreadsheet into ONE Link Field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/295801/migrate-multiple-urls-from-a-spreadsheet-into-one-link-field)

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom process is the answer (as it usually is):

Migration:

```
source:
  plugin: d7_paragraphs_item
  bundle: BUNDLE
process:
  d10_link_field:
    plugin: field_link_custom
    source: d7_link_field
    title_source: d7_title_field
```

And the plugin:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\MODULE_migrate\Plugin\migrate\process;

use Drupal\link\Plugin\migrate\process\FieldLink;
use Drupal\migrate\MigrateExecutableInterface;
use Drupal\migrate\Row;

/**
 * Extension of the field_link plugin to handle multiple source fields.
 *
 * Add to the process section of the migration YML:
 *
 * @code
 * field_destination:
 *   plugin: field_link_custom
 *   source: field_source
 *   title_source: field_title_source
 * @endcode
 *
 * @MigrateProcessPlugin(
 *   id = "field_link_custom",
 *   handle_multiples = TRUE
 * )
 */
class FieldLinkCustom extends FieldLink {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function transform($value, MigrateExecutableInterface $migrate_executable, Row $row, $destination_property) {
    $route = parent::transform($value[0], $migrate_executable, $row, $destination_property);
    $route['title'] = $row->getSourceProperty($this->configuration['title_source'])[0]['value'];
    return $route;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this, without any custom process plugin:

```
process:
  'd10_link_field/uri': d7_link_field/0/url
  'd10_link_field/title': d7_title_field/0/value
```

Most custom D7 fields are multivalue by default, so you need the **/0/** to access its first value.
D7 Link and Text fields have a different structure so you need to check whether the value is in a **value** or **url** subfield.

You can use the [Migrate Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_devel) module to inspect the migrations while working on them.