# Migrate a multiple date-range field from CSV using Migrate Source CSV-module

Tags: migrations, configuration, importing-exporting

I need to migrate data from a csv file to Drupal 9 (using $ as delimiter for fields). The field csv_date_options can contain multiple date ranges with | as delimiter. The CSV-file looks like this:

```
id$title$body$csv_date_options
1$Drupal workshop$some body text$13.01.2021-15.01.2021|23.03.2021-25.03.2021|04.11.2021-06.11.2021
2$Another workshop$again some body text$25.04.2021-30.04.2021
```

My Drupal 9 site has a content type workshops with 3 field: *title*, *body* and field_date_options. field_date_options is a date-range-field with unlimited entries.

Tried to apply this solution which has a similar logic: [Possible to extract multiple key/value pairs (links) from string in CSV and migrate into multiple link field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/254248/possible-to-extract-multiple-key-value-pairs-links-from-string-in-csv-and-migr?rq=1)

But my migration fails. Here is my migration-yml:

```
id: workshops-5
label: Import workshops
migration_group: default

source:
  plugin: 'csv'
  # Full path to the file.
  path: '/my-path-to-csv/workshops.csv'
  delimiter: '$'
  enclosure: '"'
  header_row_count: 1
  ids:
    - id
  fields:
    0:
      name: id
      label: 'Unique Id'
    1:
      name: title
      label: 'Titel'
    2:
      name: body
      label: 'Workshop Description'
    3:
      name: field_date_options
      label: 'Date options'


process:
  title: title
  body: body

  all_dates: 
   -
     source: csv_date_options
     plugin: explode
     limit: 30
     delimiter: '|' 
   -
     plugin: explode
     delimiter: '-'

  field_date_options:
    -
      plugin: sub_process
      source: '@all_dates'
      process:
        value: #try to set the field_date_options/value
          -
            plugin: extract
            index: 
              -'0'
          -
            plugin: format_date
            from_format: 'd.m.Y'
            to_format: 'Y-m-d'

        end_value: #try to set the field_date_options/end_value
          -
            plugin: extract
            index:
              -'1'
          -
            plugin: format_date
            from_format: 'd.m.Y'
            to_format: 'Y.m.d'

  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: workshops

destination:
  plugin: entity:node
```

What am I missing? Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Try deleting line 5 and see if you can import the rest of the file.  When debugging, you want to determine if you can import part of the file (some lines) or none at all.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help. I edited the question since I found a similar case, but can't figure out how to apply the solution for my case. Still struggling.

Comment: You have to try to isolate where the migration is failing. Which lines of the file are causing the failure?  Which columns in the CSV file?  Make the simplest possible example you can that causes the failure, and then describe the specific failure and what you expect to happen.

Comment: It fails when I execute "drush migrate:import workshops-5". Wenn I run "drush mmsg" I just see the message "Not enough arguments (missing: "migration-id")". This is the simplest possible example. I need to import multiple date-rages. A single date-range is working so far.